# JSON Object Cache With Property Expiration For GraphQL Responses

Tags: algorithm, caching, data-structures, hash, graphql

I have created a cache (nosql) that takes graphQL json objects and flattens them out. Meaning that all child objects are replaced with references and stored separately. For example given the below input:

```
{
    "users": [
         {"type": "user", "id": 1, "name": "bob"}, {"type": "user", "id": 1, "name": "bill"}
    ]
}
```

It Is Stored As:

```
{ 
    "users": ["ref-user-1", "ref-user-2"],
    "ref-user-1": {"type": "user", "id": 1, "name": "bob"},
    "ref-user-2": {"type": "user", "id": 1, "name": "bill"}
}
```

This benefit of this approach is that if another request with information on `user-1` we can update our local data store. And then if a request comes through for user by id we might have all of the required information.

The issues comes with cache invalidation. How do we know if a cache entry is up to date? For the sake of this post we can say an object is valid if all of its fields have been cached within 2 hours. If another request comes in with `user-1` we would like to update our local timestamps for the fields returned by that request.

How do I keep per field time stamps in a performant manner?

Considered Options:

1. Each value gets its own timestamp. All look ups would be O(1), but we would have a ton of duplicate timestamp data.

   `"ref-user-1": {"type": "user", 
                  "id": {"val": 1, "ts": "1557941674"}, 
                  "name": {"val": "bob" "ts": "1557941674"}}`
2. Storing property timestamps as property sets with a single timestamp per set. Look ups would be slow, but it would reduce data. Updates could also be pretty slow. It would be nice if we could turn the fields into a hash, and the check if the larger hash contained all of the fields in the smaller hash.

   `"ref-user-1": {"type": "user", "id": 1, "name": "bob", 
                  "field_sets": ["ts": "1557941674", "fields": ["id", "name"]] }`
3. A fancy data structure I haven't considered...

Answer (score 1):

As the old joke says, "There are only two hard problems in computer science.  Naming, cache invalidation, and off by one errors."

So this is a hard problem, and should be hard.

I would suggest that what matters is not how recently the data was returned, but instead how recently the data was cached.  Otherwise a commonly requested piece of data can get out of date and remain so indefinitely.  (See, I said that cache invalidation is hard!)

That suggests that timestamps should be based on when the cache was most recently updated.  So you could just return the data if it is less than 1.5 hours old.  If it is 1.5-2 hours old you flip a coin. (with increasing probability of flipping it).  If older, you treat it as invalid.  This strategy makes it likely that data is only requested once for a refresh, even if it is very actively accessed.

This approach requires a per property timestamp.  And allows a job that knows that it changed some of this data to preemptively invalidate some fields.  When you go to fill the object you know that this happened because there is a reference to data that isn't there, and you know that you need to refresh it.  (Whether refreshing is handled at the caching or application layer is a design decision that can go either way.)

Comment: By "returned" I meant returned by the server, so how recently it was cached. Interesting approach with the secondary job for cleaning.